# Download Oracle Database 8i

Tags: database, oracle, legacy

Where can I download old versions of Oracle database, specifically 8.1.7
I need the 8.1.7 client for linux, if it exists.
I know it's ancient, but I am supporting legacy systems.

Comment: I feel bad for you :(

Comment: You can use an Oracle 9i or 10g client to connect to an 8.1.7 database - have done so myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle don't make them available. In fact, you can't even get 10.2 and 11.1 without a valid (paid-up) licence. See [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a valid support contract, you can log a service request on Metalink and Oracle will provide you with whatever ancient software you need.  Oracle doesn't make older versions of software available for public download.